# How do I use Hyper-V with multiple monitor monitor support but leaving one?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hyper-v

I currently have 3 monitors but I need to use Virtual Machine remotely on two monitors and on one native OS or some other application. When I connect to VM and check "Use All My Monitor", in full screen mode it displays to all three monitors. But I want it to only occupy two in full screen mode leaving one for other tasks. Is this possible?